wording that does not exclude other possible conditions to the precedent
VERSION A:
"determining a winner on a condition that the highest score is at least five points greater than the second highest score"
Suppose that the above sentence is on a patent claim.
In the specifications it explicitly states that the article "a" shall mean one or more. I am aware that this is also the default meaning.
Given all of that, is the sentence correctly worded in that there may be other conditions used to determine a winner, not just the one mentioned.
Or, do I need to change the sentence to something like:
VERSION B:
"determining a winner at least in part on a condition that the highest score is at least five points greater than the second highest score"

I recommend version B to avoid relying on the definition of “a”.

Even though version B is better, do you agree that version A is still technically correct and carries the intended meaning and therefore coverage and protection?

Judges and juries will read your claims to make a decision. District court judges may have very little experience with patent law. Even in the specialized patent appeals court it is rare for a judge to have been a patent attorney or even have any technical background at all.
